# Como solucionar #1005 - No puedo crear tabla; error: Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" al exportar base de datos desde MySQL?

Tags: exportar

Intento exportar una base de datos de MySQL, utilizo el siguiente código para intentar realizarlo desde un script:

```
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$database_name="bd_venta_servicios";

$conexion=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database_name);
$tables=array();
$sql="SHOW TABLES";
$result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
$tables[]=$row[0];
}

$backupSQL="";
foreach($tables as $table){
$query="SHOW CREATE TABLE $table";
$result=mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$backupSQL.="\n\n".$row[1].";\n\n";

$query="SELECT * FROM $table";
$result=mysqli_query($conexion,$query);

$columnCount=mysqli_num_fields($result);

for($i=0;$i<$columnCount;$i++){
while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
$backupSQL.="INSERT INTO $table VALUES(";
for($j=0;$j<$columnCount;$j++){
$row[$j]=$row[$j];

if(isset($row[$j])){
$backupSQL.='"'.$row[$j].'"';
}else{
$backupSQL.='""';
}
if($j<($columnCount-1)){
$backupSQL.=',';
}
}
$backupSQL.=");\n";
}
}
$backupSQL.="\n";
}

if(!empty($backupSQL)){
$backup_file_name=$database_name.'_backup_'.time().'.sql';
$fileHandler=fopen($backup_file_name,'w+');
$number_of_lines=fwrite($fileHandler,$backupSQL);
fclose($fileHandler);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($backup_file_name));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($backup_file_name));
ob_clean();
flush();
}
?>
```

Al ejecutar el código, se descarga un archivo .SQL ; el cual contiene solo parte de las tablas que existen en mi DB, en total tengo 8 tablas y solamente me muestra 4 tablas al importar en PHPMyAdmin  el archivo EXPORTADO ; y además me genera el siguiente error:

```
CREATE TABLE `detalle_solicitud_servicio` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_solicitud_servicio` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_servicio` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_personal_servicio` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_vehiculo` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `comentario` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_servicio` (`id_servicio`),
  KEY `id_vehiculo` (`id_vehiculo`),
  KEY `id_personal_servicio` (`id_personal_servicio`),
  KEY `id_solicitud_servicio` (`id_solicitud_servicio`),
  CONSTRAINT `detalle_solicitud_servicio_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_servicio`) REFERENCES `servicios` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `detalle_solicitud_servicio_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_vehiculo`) REFERENCES `vehiculos` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `detalle_solicitud_servicio_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_personal_servicio`) REFERENCES `personal_servicio` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `detalle_solicitud_servicio_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`id_solicitud_servicio`) REFERENCES `solicitud_servicio` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB [...]

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1005 - No puedo crear tabla `prueba`.`detalle_solicitud_servicio` (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

El archivo .SQL exportado contiene esto:

`introducir el código aquí CREATE TABLE`clientes`(`id`int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`apellidos`varchar(40) NOT NULL,`nombres`varchar(40) NOT NULL,`dni`int(8) NOT NULL,`fecha_nacimiento`date NOT NULL,`telefono`int(20) NOT NULL,`correo`varchar(40) NOT NULL,`direccion`varchar(40) NOT NULL,`estado `varchar(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO clientes VALUES("18","Pita Lezama","Hernan","46066038","0000-00-00","958124483","rosypl@outlook.com","Pasaje Las Casuarinas S/N","Activo");
INSERT INTO clientes VALUES("19","Sanchez Sanchez ","Jose Carlos","26897654","0000-00-00","976543416","uarit_t234@outlokk.com","Ingresar Direccion","Activo");
INSERT INTO clientes VALUES("21","Hurtado Garcia","Mario","26543212","1996-02-13","934232123","hocrt3923@hotmail.com","Los Perolitos 456","Activo");
INSERT INTO clientes VALUES("22","Municipalidad Los Baños del Ica",".","2147483647","1960-02-02","975432123","mdbi2020@gmail.com","Av Atahualpa 200","Activo");
INSERT INTO clientes VALUES("23","Nuñez Terrones ","Carlos","26604838","1989-02-12","987843660","carnuñez@hotmail.com","jr. petunias 345","Activo");
INSERT INTO clientes VALUES("24","Llanos Sanchez","Oscar Rodrigo","46340992","1982-09-23","944309121","llanososcar@hotmail.com","jr.el ingenio 4405","Activo");
INSERT INTO clientes VALUES("26","Calderon Aliaga","Antonio Mercedes","44213446","1989-05-01","912345654","alamarcal2134@outlook.com","Av. Atahualpa 345","Activo");

CREATE TABLE `detalle_solicitud_servicio` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_solicitud_servicio` int(20) NOT NULL,
`id_servicio` int(20) NOT NULL,
`id_personal_servicio` int(20) NOT NULL,
`id_vehiculo` int(20) NOT NULL,
`comentario` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`estado` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `id_servicio` (`id_servicio`),
KEY `id_vehiculo` (`id_vehiculo`),
KEY `id_personal_servicio` (`id_personal_servicio`),
KEY `id_solicitud_servicio` (`id_solicitud_servicio`),
CONSTRAINT `detalle_solicitud_servicio_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_servicio`) REFERENCES `servicios` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `detalle_solicitud_servicio_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_vehiculo`) REFERENCES `vehiculos` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `detalle_solicitud_servicio_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_personal_servicio`) REFERENCES `personal_servicio` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `detalle_solicitud_servicio_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`id_solicitud_servicio`) REFERENCES `solicitud_servicio` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=200 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO detalle_solicitud_servicio VALUES("191","116","6","10","11","limpia bien la cadena","Atendido");
INSERT INTO detalle_solicitud_servicio VALUES("192","117","16","10","15","arreglar bien los frenos","Atendido");
INSERT INTO detalle_solicitud_servicio VALUES("193","118","2","15","16",".","Atendido");
INSERT INTO detalle_solicitud_servicio VALUES("195","120","5","10","18","Limpiar bien","Atendido");
INSERT INTO detalle_solicitud_servicio VALUES("196","121","13","9","17","-","Atendido");
INSERT INTO detalle_solicitud_servicio VALUES("197","122","2","15","17","Limpiar bien","Atendido");
INSERT INTO detalle_solicitud_servicio VALUES("198","122","15","10","18","Limpiar bien","Atendido");
INSERT INTO detalle_solicitud_servicio VALUES("199","123","15","10","10","Limpiar bien","Atendido");

CREATE TABLE `personal_servicio` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Dni` int(10) NOT NULL,
`apellidos` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`nombres` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`telefono` int(10) NOT NULL,
`especialidad` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`estado` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO personal_servicio VALUES("9","43234589","Cuzco Salazar","Manuel","976543453","Electricidad","Activo");
INSERT INTO personal_servicio VALUES("10","43234589","Cuzco Salazar","Manuel","976543453","Mecanica","Activo");
INSERT INTO personal_servicio VALUES("15","41121345","Sanchez Sanchez","Ramon Antonio","923456765","Mecanica","Activo");

CREATE TABLE `servicios` (
`id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`descripcion` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`precio` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
`especialidad` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`estado` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO servicios VALUES("1","Descarbonización de Válvulas","40.00","Mecanica","Disponible");
INSERT INTO servicios VALUES("2","Afinamiento","30.00","Mecanica","Disponible");
INSERT INTO servicios VALUES("5","Cambio de Árbol de levas","60.00","Mecanica","Disponible");
INSERT INTO servicios VALUES("6","Cambio de cadena de Distribución","85.00","Mecanica","Disponible");
INSERT INTO servicios VALUES("9","Cambio de alternador","60.00","Electricidad","Disponible");
INSERT INTO servicios VALUES("12","Canbio de fusible","10.00","Electricidad","Disponible");
INSERT INTO servicios VALUES("13","Cableado eléctrico","80.00","Electricidad","Disponible");
INSERT INTO servicios VALUES("14","Carga de Bateria","6.00","Electricidad","Disponible");
INSERT INTO servicios VALUES("15","Mant. sistema de arrastre","15.00","Mecanica","Disponible");
INSERT INTO servicios VALUES("16","Mant. frenos","10.00","Mecanica","Disponible");
INSERT INTO servicios VALUES("17","Mant. electrico","20.00","Electricidad","Disponible");

CREATE TABLE `solicitud_servicio` (
`id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_venta` int(20) NOT NULL,
`area` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`especialidad` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`fecha` date NOT NULL,
`estado` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `id_venta` (`id_venta`),
CONSTRAINT `solicitud_servicio_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_venta`) REFERENCES `ventas` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=124 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO solicitud_servicio VALUES("116","57",".","Mecanica","2022-01-27","Atendida");
INSERT INTO solicitud_servicio VALUES("117","59","catastro","Mecanica","2022-01-27","Atendida");
INSERT INTO solicitud_servicio VALUES("118","58","osi","Mecanica","2022-01-27","Atendida");
INSERT INTO solicitud_servicio VALUES("120","61","Catastro","Mecanica","2022-02-05","Atendida");
INSERT INTO solicitud_servicio VALUES("121","61","Soporte","Electricidad","2022-02-05","Atendida");
INSERT INTO solicitud_servicio VALUES("122","61","Proyectos","Mecanica","2022-02-05","Atendida");
INSERT INTO solicitud_servicio VALUES("123","62","Soporte","Mecanica","2022-05-26","Atendida");

CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`dni` int(8) NOT NULL,
`cargo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`usuario` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`clave` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`correo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`estado` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES("10","23231234","Administrador","admin","d033e22ae348aeb5660fc2140aec35850c4da997","migsbaz@gmail.com","Activo");
INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES("18","42345643","Vendedor","Jorge","33f927344e079e00d3fa45d8833b04e735223eec","migsbaz@hotmail.com","Activo");
INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES("25","41673456","Pers.Serv.","ramon","2bfe2630cd649d2b7fecaff845d0a28fb600f4a0","rsanchez20@hotmail.com","Activo");
INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES("26","26543251","Vendedor","jesica","50150b55a23f212ca4918b4b7a7bebad84040652","jesi300mar@yahoo.com","Activo");
INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES("33","41397784","Administrador","mas","5f8992a5f5df2e39cfdeb44c93f510059a99dc51","migsbaz@gmail.com","Activo");

CREATE TABLE `vehiculos` (
`id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_cliente` int(20) NOT NULL,
`placa` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`marca` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`modelo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`color` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`estado` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `id_cliente` (`id_cliente`),
CONSTRAINT `vehiculos_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_cliente`) REFERENCES `clientes` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO vehiculos VALUES("10","18","JU 3456","Italika","GY200","Roja","Activo");
INSERT INTO vehiculos VALUES("11","19","HJ5643","Yamaha","UH654","Negro","Inactivo");
INSERT INTO vehiculos VALUES("15","21","UN 5678","Suzuki","TS 200","Amarillo","Activo");
INSERT INTO vehiculos VALUES("16","22","KHG 5432","Honda ","XLR 200","Rojo","Activo");
INSERT INTO vehiculos VALUES("17","22","KHH 3434","Honda","XLR 200","Rojo","Activo");
INSERT INTO vehiculos VALUES("18","22","KTR 6577","Honda ","XLR 200","Rojo","Activo");
INSERT INTO vehiculos VALUES("21","26","SW213","Honda","XL125","rojo","Activo");

CREATE TABLE `ventas` (
`id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_usuario` int(20) NOT NULL,
`id_cliente` int(20) NOT NULL,
`tipo_venta` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`tipo_comprobante` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`forma_pago` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`importe` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
`fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
`estado` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `id_cliente` (`id_cliente`),
KEY `id_usuario` (`id_usuario`),
CONSTRAINT `ventas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_cliente`) REFERENCES `clientes` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `ventas_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuario`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=63 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO ventas VALUES("57","10","19","Contado","Factura","Efectivo","100.30","2022-01-27 14:31:51","Realizada");
INSERT INTO ventas VALUES("58","10","22","Contado","Factura","Deposito","35.40","2022-01-27 14:41:35","Realizada");
INSERT INTO ventas VALUES("59","10","21","Contado","Factura","Efectivo","11.80","2022-01-27 14:42:52","Realizada");
INSERT INTO ventas VALUES("61","33","22","Contado","Boleta","Efectivo","185.00","2022-02-05 19:53:07","Realizada");
INSERT INTO ventas VALUES("62","33","18","Contado","Factura","Efectivo","17.70","2022-05-26 10:30:40","Realizada");

Espero por favor alguna sugerencia para corregir este error,  gracias de antemano

Comment: Toma en cuenta el orden de las tablas. No puedes hacer referencia a `servicios` desde `detalle_solicitud_servicio` si aún no ha sido creada `servicios`, ya que alfabéticamente -como resulta de `SHOW TABLES`- su script de creación viene después. U ordenas los scripts por dependencias  o añades los FK después de haber creado todas las tablas sin ellos. Como alternativa puedes hacer el respaldo con [**mysqldump**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html).

Comment: No tenías necesidad de PHP para crear una copia de tu base de datos. La puedes generar desde el mismo mysql, mediante el comando [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html). Este comando te creará la BD en el orden correcto, cosa que no ocurre aquí, y es que como te indica @Sal, si una tabla depende de otra, no puedes crear dicha tabla sin que aún exista la tabla de la que depende.

Comment: Gracias por responderme amigos, comprendo que deberia hacerlo desde mysqldump, el detalle es como facilito al usuario final del sistema el acceso a terminal, ya que si bien yo puedo ejecutarlo desde la terminal mysql , para el usuario del sistema no le resultatia tan facil llegar ahi, se requiere q el respaldo se pueda hacer de manera facil. O es que hay alguna forma ejecutar el comando desde una pagina?

Comment: Que un usuario tenga que hacer sus respaldos es un caso de uso cuestionable; no obstante, podrías usar [funciones de ejecución de programas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.exec.php) si se encuentran habilitadas en el servidor.